# PHP validation code for subscriber toll dialing (STD) codes in India

Tags: php, validation

I did a lot of google to get the PHP validation code for validating the available STD codes in India, but couldn't get it. If somebody has the STD validation code please help me out of this issue. Thanks in Advance. I

Comment: i tried to search if there is a format in which these numbers are genereated but couldnt find an adequate solution. These links might be helpful [std code numbreing](http://idg.ceeri.ernet.in/~raj/misc/phones.html) and [Wikipedia article on Telephone numbers in india](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_India)

Comment: @PruthviNag. Yes it's a quite useful article.

Answer (score 3):

Prepare your own validation code..

Make a list of all the available codes and store them in an array... Now check the entered code using `in_array()`

```
<?php
$os = array("079", "040", "0891");
if (in_array($_POST['std'], $os)) {
    echo "Valid";
} else {
    echo "Enter a valid code";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but if you could tell me where should I get the complete array of STD codes, I would be thankful to you.

Comment: @Sushil [Check this](http://indiapages.in/stdcodes.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You should collect and store std codes in DB and need to validate from server side... Codings are same as ordinary email 
exists validation... :)

Comment: I want to check the STD code just like we check Mobile No. For that I don't think the DB is needed. Some magic code should achieve this.